# Add css-file to single-post-template based on category

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using this function (in `function.php`) to add a template for specific category slug, however I also wish to use a specific css-file, however I don't know how to embed it correctly in the filter. I tried below, but this just renders a blank page (so php-error), thankful for any help:

Original code, which enables templates for post categories to be created (i.e. "single-categoryname.php") in Function.php:

```
add_filter('single_template', create_function(
    '$the_template',
    'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
        if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
        return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php";
        }
    return $the_template;' )
);
```

My failed atempt to include an external css:

```
        add_filter('single_template', create_function(
            '$the_template',
            'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
                if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
                return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php",

       //my code:
       wp_enqueue_style( 'single-{$cat->slug}', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/single-{$cat->slug}.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');  
      }
            return $the_template;' )
      });
```

Comment: Please do include any indication of what happens when you use wp_enqueue_style.  There is almost no information embedded in the phrase "//My failed attempt to include a css-file". Is there any output logged, or stack trace visible, as a result of the attempt to execute the code ?  Have you tried to set up logging or debugging ?

Comment: Sorry, I get a PHP-error so the whole page just renders out blank.

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction.  It's good for a post, and for the troubleshooting process, if you can copy the text of that error.  You may have to work with PHP logging to work out how to do that sort of thing, but it'll be useful

Comment: I get this when debugging: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'single' (T_STRING) in /www/webvol18/td/5azsfnodhbyqngs/utt.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/utt.se/functions.php on line 49"

Comment: I note that,  in your answer,  the if's return end in a semicolon,  while in your question,  it ends in a comma.  Out of curiosity,  which line was line 49 from your original post?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't added CSS for specific templates so I've mashed up the following from one of my own projects (simplified) and the [is_page_template](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) function.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mcd_theme_styles');

if( !function_exists("mcd_theme_styles") ) {
    function mcd_theme_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'some-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/dist/css/some-css.css', array(), '1.4', 'all' );

        if ( is_page_template( 'templates/about.php' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'some-css' );
        }

        if ( is_singular() ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'different-css' );
        }
    }
}
```

It answers the first part of the question, does that help with the second?

Answer (score 0):

So, after some googling I actually found a really easy answer to this:

```
add_filter('single_template', create_function(
    '$the_template',
    'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
        if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
        return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php";
        return STYLESHEETPATH . "css/single-{$cat->slug}.css";
        }
    return $the_template;' )
);
```